# Using Grunt and Uglify to version control

Tags: javascript, regex, gruntjs, uglifyjs

I have a bunch of modules described in the following document tree:

```
.
├── Gruntfile.js
├── build
└── src
    └── app
        ├── Render
        │   ├── api
        │   │   ├── common.js
        │   │   ├── v1.js
        │   │   └── v2.js
        │   └── module.json
        └── User
            ├── api
            │   ├── common.js
            │   ├── v1.js
            │   └── v2.js
            └── module.json
```

Where `/src/app/Render/` and `/src/app/User/` are both considered modules.

Inside the `Gruntfile.js` I wish to declare a list of included modules and default version like so:

```
var modules=["Render", "User"];
var version = 2;
```

Using this information I would like to traverse each of the modules folders, and `uglify` to package files in `./api/` including anything that matches the regular expression `/^v[version]\./` (`version` refers to the variable and not a string literal) and omitting anything that matches the regular expression `/^v(?!version\.)[0-9]+\./`, then uglify them and store the file in `/build/app/{{Module}}/api.js`.

For example if `version=2` is given I would like to end up with the following structure:

```
   ...
    ├── build
    │   └── app
    │       ├── Render
   ...      │   └── api.js // /src/app/Render/api/v2.js + /src/app/Render/api/common.js
            │   
            └── User
                └── api.js // /src/app/User/api/v2.js + /src/app/User/api/common.js
```

I will allow the user to run the task with a shell flag like so: `grunt deploy --v=2` which would override the explicit `var version = 2;`

The issue is I do not get how to iterate over my array during a task and select the files I want (I've seen globbing but it doesn't seem advanced enough to select the files I want) and perform a separate `uglify` operation on each. I would really appreciate some advice.

Comment: +1 purely for the patience you must have had to draw out those tree views with pipes and dashes.

Comment: @AntP You might have to revoke it: [Tree (Unix)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(Unix)) ;)

Comment: In that case, +1 for a neat trick I wasn't aware of (did have a hunch).

Answer (score 0):

One thing that people ignore so often is that you have the full power of Node.js in your Gruntfile.

```
var modules=["Render", "User"];
var version = grunt.option('version', 2);
var _ = require('underscore');
var fs = require('fs');

grunt.initConfig({

  uglify: _.reduce(modules, function(obj, module){

    obj[module] = {
      files: {},
      options: {
        // Add your options here
      }
    };

    obj[module].files['build/app/'+module+'/api.js'] =
      _.chain(fs.readdirSync('./src/app/'+module+'/api'))
        .filter(function(filename){
            // Check against your regular expression here
        })
        .map(function(filename){
            return './src/app/'+module+'/api/'+filename
        })
        .value();

    return obj;

  }, {});
})
```